# Neo4j - Create relationship within label on property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm importing a dataset of the following structure into Neo4j:

```
|     teacher     | student | period |
|:---------------:|---------|:------:|
| Mr. Smith       | Michael | 1      |
| Mrs. Oliver     | Michael | 2      |
| Mrs. Roth       | Michael | 3      |
| Mrs. Oliver     | Michael | 4      |
| Mrs. Oliver     | Susan   | 1      |
| Mrs. Roth       | Susan   | 2      |
```

My goal is to create a graph where a teacher "sends" students from one period to the next, showing the flow of students between teachers. The above graph for instance, would look like this:

[image: teacher_graph]

Using words, my logic looks like this:

1. Generate a unique node for every teacher
2. For each student, create a relationship connecting the earliest period to the next earliest period, until the latest period is reached.

My code so far completes the first step:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///neo_sample.csv' AS row // loads local file
MERGE(a:teacher {teacher: row.teacher}) // used merge instead of create to produce unique teacher nodes.
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the queries you plan to run on such a graph? With this current model, you will of course need to have a relationship per student per period change, with the student name or id on each relationship, and likely with the period number (or numbers) for the transition.

Comment: I wrote the above problem as a simplified version of my actual problem. I'm actually dealing with medical data. Teachers = physician IDs, students = patient IDs, and period = date of service. Things I'd like to query: 1) Which physicians form care networks (community detection) 2) Which physicians are gatekeepers to certain types of care (betweenness centrality) 3) Use a path finding algorithm based on cost and outcome to find the most cost effective way to treat various illnesses 4) For physicians who are not subscribed to x, use link prediction algorithms to find candidates for x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can produce your illustrated graph.

Assuming your CSV file looks like this:

```
teacher;student;period
Mr. Smith;Michael;1
Mrs. Oliver;Michael;2
Mrs. Roth;Michael;3
Mrs. Oliver;Michael;4
Mrs. Oliver;Susan;1
Mrs. Roth;Susan;2
```

then this query should work:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///neo_sample.csv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH row.teacher AS t, row.student AS s, row.period AS p
ORDER BY p
WITH s, COLLECT({t:t, p:p}) AS data
FOREACH(i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(data)-2) |
  MERGE(a:Teacher {name: data[i].t})
  MERGE(b:Teacher {name: data[i+1].t})
  MERGE (a)-[:SENDS {student: s, period: data[i].p}]->(b)
)
```

Comment: I can confirm this works as intended. I've looked at this a few times over the past week, and I'm having having trouble understanding a few pieces of the syntax. 

In the FOREACH clause, why do we subtract two from SIZE(data)? Is part of that subtraction to account for dropping the header? 

Also, I can see syntactically what you did with the period symbol with data[i].t, data[i+1].t, and data[i].p values, but I haven't seen someone do that before in Cypher. Is there a word associated with that dot technique?

Comment: We subtract 2 because the last `data` element has no "next teacher" to use for `b`. The "dot" is just used to reference a property value of a map -- it is standard syntax.